# Silverlight: How do I design a custom layout control?

Tags: silverlight

I want to create a custom control named DetailRegion that accepts a collection of child controls. From there I want layout the controls in a manner of my choosing. For example...

```
<localControls:DetailRegion>
    <TextBlock Text="Occupation:" Style="{StaticResource Label}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Occupation}" Style="{StaticResource Value}" />
</localControls:DetailRegion>
```

... may be rendered as a grid with two columns or a stack panel depending on screen width.

I'm not asking for a complete solution, I just need tutorial to get me started.

Comment: Why not try a WrapPanel?

Comment: Check this series of articles: http://blogs.claritycon.com/leeroth/category/custom-panels/ The author implements the wrap panel which is similar to what you need.

Comment: @Xin, the layout I need is actually quite a bit more complex than the example I gave above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Msdn have also good [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903936%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), where custom panel creation is described.